# Run textillate.js animation on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to have an animation run every time a user mouses over a menu item.

Currently the animation only runs the first time you mouse over and not on successive attempts.

I'm using [textillate.js](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/).

Code:

```
$("#menu a").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).textillate({ in: { effect: 'flash' } });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to add `loop: true` to the settings object you pass to textillate?

Comment: This makes the animation run indefinitely.  I want it to run one time, every time the menu item is hovered over.

Comment: I don't think the plugin supports this or if it does then it isn't a documented feature :(

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize the plugin without running the animation by setting `autoStart: false`. Then it's simply a matter of manually starting the animation on mouseenter with `$elem.textillate('start');`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jschr/rJ7gz/)